# Sort JButtons in JPanel

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, collections, grid-layout

I am creating a chess game using Java, everything was fine when I saw that the JButtons are not added to the JPanel in order, that is, the (0,0) is not in the same position as it would be using System.out.Println Does anyone know how I could solve it?

```
private void configurarCaselles() {
    Insets marge = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < t.getTaulerCaselles().length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.getTaulerCaselles()[0].length; j++) {
            Casella_Grafic c = t.getFitxaGrafic(i, j);
            c.setMargin(marge);

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
            c.setIcon(icon);
            if ((i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1) || (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
    chessBoard.add(new JLabel(""));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        chessBoard.add(new JLabel(COLS.substring(i, i + 1), SwingConstants.CENTER));

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    chessBoard.add(new JLabel("" + (9 - (j + 1)), SwingConstants.CENTER));
                default:
                    chessBoard.add(t.getFitxaGrafic(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[Icons Extracted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209650/example-images-for-code-and-mark-up-qas/19209651#19209651)

Comment: Which JButtons? Ca you show an example of the code for println versus the JButtons, with actual and expected results to diagnose?

Comment: Updated, the JButtons are the "Casella_Grafic" object

Comment: What kind of layout does `chessBoard` has?

Comment: A grid layout ```chessBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 9))```

Comment: BTW - glad you found the chess set in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556) helpful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are iterating your double array of `JButton`s over rows then over columns (top to bottom, then left to right) when adding the to the `chessBoard`:

```
chessBoard.add(t.getFitxaGrafic(i, j));
```

when it should be the opposite (columns then rows), so you just need to swap the `i` and `j`:

```
chessBoard.add(t.getFitxaGrafic(j, i));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okey solved, the problem was I had to swapp the letters when I add the button to grid: ```chessBoard.add(t.getFitxaGrafic(j, i));``` can you update the answer and I'll accept it? :) Thanks you for your help

Comment: Yes, swapping the indexes of the of the buttons was simpler than swapping the indexes of the iterators. Glad to help.